# Inserting data to MySQL with VB .NET

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, insert

Please help, whats wrong with my vb.net code to insert values in an MySQL database

```
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ibdm").ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO configs(configType, portsStatus, bandwidthLimit, ports, user) values(@config, @manage, @limit, @ports, @user)", conn)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
        iReturn = True
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        iReturn = False
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: Can you give some indication of the error you are getting to help solve yout problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to specify value in quote's like
Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO configs(configType, portsStatus, bandwidthLimit, ports, user) values('@config', '@manage', '@limit', '@ports', '@user')", conn)

Answer (score 0):

User my be a reserved word, try putting it in square brackets:

```
Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO configs(configType, portsStatus, bandwidthLimit, ports, [user]) values(@config, @manage, @limit, @ports, @user)", conn)
```